# How to insert a existing json data into new object?

Tags: jquery, json, hierarchy

I have a json data is in this form

```
[ { id: '1', name: 'Plant Director', parentJobID: -1 },
  { id: '19', name: 'Operations Director', parentJobID: 1 },
  { id: '16',
    name: 'Financial planning and costs Manager',
    parentJobID: 19 },
  { id: '14', name: 'Cost Analyst', parentJobID: 16 },
  { id: '15', name: 'Head of Costs', parentJobID: 16 },
  { id: '17', name: 'Manufacturing Manager', parentJobID: 19 },
  { id: '2', name: 'Head of Security', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '3', name: 'Asistente Ejecutiva', parentJobID: 2 },
  { id: '8', name: 'Jefe de Mantenimiento', parentJobID: 2 },
  { id: '27',
    name: 'Jefe Aseguramiento de Calidad',
    parentJobID: 2 },
  { id: '28', name: 'Jefe Seguridad Alimentaria', parentJobID: 27 },
  { id: '33', name: 'Operario Fabricación A (2)', parentJobID: 28 },
  { id: '34', name: 'Operario Fabricación B (2)', parentJobID: 28 },
  { id: '29',
    name: 'Especialista Aseguramiento de Calidad',
    parentJobID: 27 },
  { id: '30',
    name: 'Especialista en Microbiología',
    parentJobID: 27 },
  { id: '31',
    name: 'Especialista en Evaluación Sensorial',
    parentJobID: 27 },
  { id: '32',
    name: 'Técnico Aseguramiento de Calidad',
    parentJobID: 27 },
  { id: '4', name: 'Production Manager', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '5', name: 'Head of Maintenance', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '6', name: 'Quality Control Manager', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '7', name: 'Técnico Medio Ambiente', parentJobID: 6 },
  { id: '23',
    name: 'Quality Control Technician 1',
    parentJobID: 6 },
  { id: '25', name: 'Operario Fabricación B', parentJobID: 23 },
  { id: '26', name: 'Operario Fabricación D', parentJobID: 23 },
  { id: '24',
    name: 'Quality Control Technician 2',
    parentJobID: 6 },
  { id: '9', name: 'Warehouse Manager', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '10', name: 'Head of Planning', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '20', name: 'Operario Mtto A (2)', parentJobID: 10 },
  { id: '11',
    name: 'Head of Continuous Improvement',
    parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '21', name: 'Operario Servicios A (2)', parentJobID: 11 },
  { id: '12', name: 'Head of Supplies', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '13', name: 'Process Manager', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '18', name: 'IT Manager', parentJobID: 17 },
  { id: '35', name: '[ LINEA DE PRODUCCION ]', parentJobID: 1 },
  { id: '22', name: 'Extrusion Area', parentJobID: -1 } ]
```

then i change it into hierarchy form like:

```
[ { id: '1',
    name: 'Plant Director',
    parentJobID: -1,
    children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { id: '22',
    name: 'Extrusion Area',
    parentJobID: -1,
    children: [] } ]
```

> i want to show like this
>   http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Checkbox-Tree-View-highchecktree/
>
> but in this they used item label which is not in my response  i need to change the josn in this form

```
 item:{
                id: '1',
                label: 'Plant Director',
                checked: false
            },
            children: [{
               item:{
                    id: '19',
                    label: 'Operations Director',
                    checked: false
                } 
            },{
               item:{
                    id: '35',
                    label: '[ LINEA DE PRODUCCION ]',
                    checked: false
                } 
            }
            }]
```

Comment: There is no hierarchie on your JSON

Comment: @A.Rossi : please see this [ { id: '1',
    name: 'Plant Director',
    parentJobID: -1,
    children: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { id: '22',
    name: 'Extrusion Area',
    parentJobID: -1,
    children: [] } ]

Comment: Yeah right, but from your what value should have your children from your first code?

Comment: Ok, i think i get it, children of item 1 should be item 19, item 35 that's right ?

Comment: yes right and i want to add item: as well as checked like in example so that i can show in tree view

Comment: @A.Rossi: you know how can i attached item and checked:false in this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113708/discussion-between-sumit-aggarwal-and-a-rossi).